# How to create a copied git repository that inherits updates from original

Tags: git, github

I have created a boilerplate repo that basically handles all the configurations of Webpack and NPM package publishing. I want this repo to be the base of other repositories that can use the configuration but contain project specific code, for example utility functions. I want to be able to pull any of those updated configuration changes from the original repo as I update things like Webpack or whatever else while not effecting the code within the copied repo.

***My Research:***

I looked into forking but this is not an option as Github does not allow forking into the same organization.

I looked into Duplicating (https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Alternatives-to-forking-into-the-same-account/ba-p/7428) the repo within the organization but from what I am reading (maybe I misunderstood) this requires me to change the remote of the copied repo to point to the original repo. I am guessing that will make all my push requests update the original repo.

What is the best way to do this. From what I am seeing forking within an organization would have been the best solution which is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a server-side fork to do what you're doing. You can maintain the "fork" on your own machine.

You keep two clones. One clone is from the boilerplate repo. The other is from the working repo. But *your* clone of the working repo has *two* remotes, the boilerplate repo (usually called `upstream`) and the working repo (usually called `origin`).

When you've modified the boilerplate repo from its clone, and you want everyone else to incorporate the changes, go into the working clone and pull from `upstream` and push to `origin`.

This is exactly the same as what you would do to keep any forked repo up to date manually.

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding you, "You can maintain the "fork" on your own machine" Are you saying to create a fork, if so, does this mean I have to add the fork to my personal repository? The repository the boilerplate repo lives on is an organization tied to my personal repository. I'd rather all the related repos live in the organization.

Comment: Then I suppose my assumption that a fork would work was wrong. I'd like a way to do this with all the repositories living within the organization.

Comment: I didn't say anything in my description about where the online repos live. All I described was what you do on your machine.